# Item list with text input error on Vala

Tags: programming, vala

I have an item list and I want to put a text input:

[image]

[image]

```
using Gtk;

public class TreeViewSample : Window {

    public TreeViewSample () {
        this.title = "Programa de odontologia";
        set_default_size (500,500);
        var view = new TreeView ();
        setup_treeview (view);
        add (view);
        this.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);
    // The Entry:
        Gtk.Entry entry = new Gtk.Entry ();
        this.add (entry);

        // Add a default-text:
        entry.set_text ("hello, world!");

        // Add a delete-button:
        entry.set_icon_from_icon_name (Gtk.EntryIconPosition.SECONDARY, "edit-clear");
        entry.icon_press.connect ((pos, event) => {
            if (pos == Gtk.EntryIconPosition.SECONDARY) {
                entry.set_text ("");
            }
        });

        // Print text to stdout on enter:
        entry.activate.connect (() => {
            unowned string str = entry.get_text ();
            stdout.printf ("%s\n", str);
        });
}

    private void setup_treeview (TreeView view) {

        /*
         * Use ListStore to hold accountname, accounttype, balance and
         * color attribute. For more info on how TreeView works take a
         * look at the GTK+ API.
         */

        var listmodel = new ListStore (5, typeof (string), typeof (string),
                                          typeof (string), typeof (string), typeof (string));
        view.set_model (listmodel);

        view.insert_column_with_attributes (-1, "Nombre del paciente", new CellRendererText (), "text", 0);
        view.insert_column_with_attributes (-1, "Apellido", new CellRendererText (), "text", 1);
    view.insert_column_with_attributes (-1, "Tratamiento", new CellRendererText (), "text", 2);

        var cell = new CellRendererText ();
        cell.set ("foreground_set", true);
        view.insert_column_with_attributes (-1, "Lo que debe", cell, "text", 3, "foreground", 4);


        TreeIter iter;
        listmodel.append (out iter);
        listmodel.set (iter, 0, "Agustin", 1, "Gomez", 3, "0", 2, "conducto", 4, "blue");

        listmodel.append (out iter);
        listmodel.set (iter, 0, "Laura", 1, "Gomez", 3, "$100", 2, "conducto", 4, "red");

    listmodel.append (out iter);
        listmodel.set (iter, 0, "Luis", 1, "Gomez", 3, "$400", 2, "conducto", 4, "green");
    }

    public static int main (string[] args) {
        Gtk.init (ref args);

        var sample = new TreeViewSample ();
        sample.show_all ();
        Gtk.main ();

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want [`Gtk.Overlay`](http://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Overlay.html).

That said, a better design would probably be to put both the `Gtk.TreeView` and `Gtk.Entry` an a `Gtk.Box` so the entry doesn't occlude the tree view…

Comment: I need more help please, im a beginner , i only know C programming, can you give me an example of Gtk.Overlay.
Or how to use the Gtk.treeView , Gtk.Entry and Gtk.Box, its not necesary to follow my example, i need a simple explanation
Thanks nemequ